# pushing to nexus, I get "Repository path must have another '/' after initial '/'"

Tags: python, nexus, setuptools

When running `python setup.py bdist_wheel upload -r ournexus` I get "Repository path must have another '/' after initial '/'".

I'm trying to push to a private PyPi repository on a company nexus.

Answer (score 6):

The problem was that, in my .pypirc, it said:

```
[ournexus]
repository=[my URL]/repository/[repositoryname]
username=[username]
password=[password]
```

where it should have said

```
[ournexus]
repository=[my URL]/repository/[repositoryname]/
username=[username]
password=[password]
```

(note the forward slash after [repositoryname])

Which, judging from the documentation and tutorials online seems to be fine for the public pypi, but doesn't seem to be accepted by nexus.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that `[repositoryname]` was pointing to a [Repository Group](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/pypi-repositories) while it should point to a Hosted Repository (with the trailing `/` indeed).